# what does this code do, I need to understand

Tags: java, android

If someone can explain what these lines of codes does/mean. Will be very grateful. Thanks

```
JSONObject req = new JSONObject();
boolean flag = false;
try {
    req.put("name", p_name.getText().toString());
    String res = HttpClient.SendHttpPost(Constants.NAME, req.toString());
    if(res != null){
        JSONObject json  = new JSONObject(res);
        if(json.getBoolean("status")){
            flag = true;
            String id = json.getString("userid");
            app.getUserinfo().SetUserInfo(id);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Which part if this code is not clear?

Comment: Where have you found this code, since it was not documented?

Answer (score 3):

**In brief**

This code sends a name to a remote API, which returns a userid and successful status (presumably only if the name is found by the remote service). The userid is then stored in our local application.

---

**Line by line explanation**

1. First, we create a JSON object named `req`.

   ```
   JSONObject req = new JSONObject();
   ```
2. Then we save the string stored in `p_name` to the `name` field of `req`

   ```
   boolean flag = false;
   try {
       req.put("name", p_name.getText().toString());
   ```
3. Then we HTTP POST a string serialization of the JSON object to our server. `res` will store the response we receive as a string.

   ```
   String res = HttpClient.SendHttpPost(Constants.NAME, req.toString());
   ```
4. After the POST returns, we check the response to see if it's null.

   ```
   if(res != null){
   ```
5. If it's not null, we turn the response into a JSON object (presumably this server returns valid JSON.

   ```
   JSONObject json  = new JSONObject(res);
   ```
6. We check to see if the field `status` in our response object is true. (Response would look like `{"status":"true","userid":"a-user-id"}` if you looked at the raw server output.)

   ```
   if(json.getBoolean("status")){
   ```
7. If so, we set flag to true, get the field `userid` from the response object, and set our application's user ID to the returned ID from the server.

   ```
       flag = true;
       String id = json.getString("userid");
       app.getUserinfo().SetUserInfo(id);
   ```

Answer (score 1):

```
//creating a json object
JSONObject req = new JSONObject(); 
boolean flag = false;
try {
    //save the string from p_name to the json
    req.put("name", p_name.getText().toString()); 
    //send the json string to the server
    String res = HttpClient.SendHttpPost(Constants.NAME, req.toString()); 
    if(res != null){
        //if you get the response correctly, convert the response to a json object (or we call it "parse")
        JSONObject json  = new JSONObject(res); 
        //if the "status" in the json represents true, make "flag" true and then set the user id
        if(json.getBoolean("status")){
            flag = true;
            String id = json.getString("userid");
            app.getUserinfo().SetUserInfo(id);          
        }
    }
```